# Pesquisa no Entity Framework como case sensitive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Pessoal estou usando Entity Framework 6, MySQL, ASP.NET MVC.

O problema é o seguinte: quando faço uma pesquisa pelo formulário (minha view de pesquisa) o EF está diferenciando maiúsculo de minúsculo. Quando faço a consulta diretamente no MySQL, usando no SqlYog por exemplo, não faz diferença se pesquisar maiúsculo ou minúsculo, então acredito que seja algo com o EF. Alguém pode dar um *help*?

Esse é o meu código que recebe o parâmetro (texto da pesquisa) e consulta no banco:

```
  public dynamic GetAll(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate, int limit, ClassContexto contexto)
    {
        dynamic data = null;
        try
        {

            data = limit == 0 ?
                (from p in contexto.Set<TEntity>() select p).Where(predicate).ToList() :
                (from p in contexto.Set<TEntity>() select p).Where(predicate).ToList().Take(limit);

        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            data = e.EntityValidationErrors;

            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                var x = eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name + " - - " + eve.Entry.State;

                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    data = ve.PropertyName + "--" + ve.ErrorMessage;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            try
            {
                data = erro.InnerException.ToString();
                return data;
            }
            catch
            {
                data = erro.Message.ToString();
                return data;
            }
        }
        finally
        {

        }
        return data;
    }
```

No banco, existe um registro "ANTONIO". Se pesquiso por "antonio", é retornado `null`.

Como posso mudar isso?

Answer (score 3):

Eu não entendi o seu código, mas você pode resolver seu problema usando os métodos [String.ToUpper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.toupper(v=vs.110).aspx) ou [String.ToLower](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.tolower(v=vs.110).aspx)

por exemplo:

```
var result = colecao.Where(c => c.PropriedadeStr.ToLower().Contains(palavraChave.ToLower()));
```

Comment: Eduardo, usei a sua sugestão e deu certo, obrigado.

Comment: legal @alessandremartins . só uma coisa: quando uma resposta resolve seu problema, você deve marcar ela como "aceita". mais detalhes no [tour]

Answer (score 1):

O EntityFramework faz a comparação a nível de código, onde no C# `"ANTONIO" != "antonio"`.

Não entendi em que parte do seu código você está fazendo a verificação, mas se você quiser comparar duas strings ignorando letras maiúsculas e minúsculas você pode passar o parâmetro `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` na comparação, Exemplo:

```
String.Equals("antonio", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Isso vai fazer com que a comparação ignore a diferença entre letras minúsculas e maiúsculas, porém, `"antônio"` continuará sendo diferente de `"antonio"`, se você realmente precisa levar em consideração aspectos linguísticos na comparação você deveria normalizar as duas strings antes da comparação removendo acentos, caractéres especiais e etc.